# Replicate torch normalization in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I know this question has been answered with grayscale image. But my image has three channels and I am not sure whether I am doing it correctly?
Here is pytorch code

```
transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
torchvision.transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
torchvision.transforms.Normalize([0.5820, 0.4512, 0.4023], [0.2217, 0.1858, 0.1705])])
img = Image.open("skin_cancer.jpg").convert('RGB')
img=transform(img)
print(torch.max(img[0,:,:]),torch.min(img[0,:,:]),torch.mean(img[0,:,:]))
```

I want to reproduce it in numpy

```
img = Image.open("skin_cancer.jpg").convert('RGB')
img = img.resize((224,224))
img=np.array(img)/255
img=np.moveaxis(img,2,0)
img [0,:,:] = (img [0,:,:] - 0.5820) / 0.2217
img [1,:,:] = (img [1,:,:] - 0.4512) / 0.1858
img [2,:,:] = (img [2,:,:] - 0.4023) / 0.1705

print(np.max(img[0,:,:]),np.min(img[0,:,:]),np.mean(img[0,:,:]))
```

I have two queries, Is `moveaxis` the correct approach to change image dimensions from `(224,224,3)` to `(3,224,224)` and is normalization the correct way to replicate as in pytorch.
What is a more elegant way to do this in numpy. Actually, I am using onnx and I don't want to install torch.

Output produced in numpy
`2.563400461673167 1.245668497439571 2.0800457636539056`
Output produced in pytorch
`tensor(1.6909) tensor(-0.3080) tensor(0.9488)`

Comment: `img[:, :, :, 0]` has one more dimension as expected from `(3, 224, 224)`!? Also, if the "color channel" is moved to dimension 1, shouldn't it be `img[;, 0, :, :]`, etc. then!? On the actual question: Please provide information on the said normalization (calculations or similar).

Comment: yes, you right. is the other thing okie? I want to know is numpy code is equivalent to pytorch code

Comment: Don't know. You need to provide information on the normalization, then people can answer that question.

Comment: i did not get, what information is required?

Comment: For example, the calculation used for the actual normalization. At least, an appropriate link to the documentation would've been nice: [`torchvision.transforms.Normalize`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize). Since you already divided in the beginning `img=np.array(img)/255`, all the `255 *` in the other lines must be removed. Also, you might want to correct the obvious error `0.1` instead of `0.1705`. Apart from that, the rest seems to be correct. Nevertheless, why not simply testing it with an example image, and comparing both outputs?

Comment: added, i edited the code

Comment: I corrected the calculations in your question. Please repeat your test. For some example image, I get comparable results. Deviations might be due to different resizing.

Comment: Feel free to post a full answer on your own if that fixed your initial issue.